# How to check whether the browser window is active or not?

Tags: javascript, browser, window, focus

I'm using Javascript to implement some kind of instant messaging. When a message arrives, I want to play a sound if the user is not focused on the browser window and no sound otherwise. I've seen about **window.onfocus** and **window.onblur** but these seem to be event listeners. Instead, I want something simpler which will return me true or false in a sequential code; so that

```
if (windowOpen) // user on my window
{
    playSound();
}
// do rest of the messaging
```

Is there such a simple, preferably single-line technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you have against event listeners, or why it needs to be on a single line. Seems like listeners are exactly what you need, irrespective of how many lines.

```
var focused = true;

window.onfocus = window.onblur = function(e) {
    focused = (e || event).type === "focus";
}

function yourMessagingFunc() {
    if (focused === false) {
        playSound();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Javascript so I might be wrong on this. But what I need is not "Do X when the window goes blur/focus". I need "While doing something, check if blur/focus and do X accordingly"

Comment: @user1863231 That's what the `yourMessagingFunc()` **does**. It checks to see the state of the window. If it's not focused (inactive), it runs `playSound();`. The extra code for `onfocus` and `onblur` is to track the state so that other code can know the state at any point by checking the `focused` variable

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't any single-line technique for this.

See:
http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus